# How do I query mysql database by using promises in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, protractor

How do I query mysql database by using promises in protractor?

I would like to execute different queries multiple times during test execution but my executeSelectQuery function executes in the beginning of the test and not in the end. How can I overcome this by using promises?

I also need to access the object inside executeSelectQuery and I am not being able to. Function returns undefined.

Below code is how my executeSelectQuery function looks like:

```
function executeSelectQuery(sql){
connectDatabase.connection.query(sql, function(err, data) {
    var result;
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('[ FAIL ] - Unsuccessful query execution!!!');
    }
    else{
        result = data[0].user;
        log.info('[ SUCCESS ] - Query executed successfully: ' + sql + ' with the following result ==> ' + result);
        return result;
    }
  });
```

}

This is how my test looks like:

```
it('Should navigate to webpage..', function(){
    log.info("Test is being executed..");
    login.goTo(parameters.url);
    login.login(parameters.username, parameters.password);
    helper.executeSelectQuery(query_select);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `executeSelectQuery()` function return a promise that resolves with the data.

```
executeSelectQuery = (sql) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectDatabase.connection.query(sql, (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Then resolve it in your tests

```
executeSelectQuery().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, really! I already tried similar solution, it executes query successfully, your solution also, but it doesn't solve the problem of executing these methods. These methods execute in the beginning of the test, even though I called them in the end of the test. 
Lets say we have to:
>enter username
>enter password
>log in
>execute query (last method)

This happens:
>execute query(called last inside test function)
>enter username
>enter password
>log in

Comment: Then either use `browser.wait()` on your query to add it to the control flow or control the execution yourself by using `.then()`.  `enterUserName.then(() => enterPassword.then(() => query...`

Answer (score 0):

**Keep query functions call in separate 'it' block in the last**.

```
describe('Overall Test Suite',function() {
 var expectedResult; //global variable for all 'it' blocks inside suite.
 it('Should navigate to webpage..', function(){
    log.info("Test is being executed..");
    login.goTo(parameters.url);
    login.login(parameters.username, parameters.password);
  });

it('Executing Queries', function(){
    expect(helper.executeSelectQuery(query_select)).toBeEqual(expectedResult);//let jasmine resolve the promise implicitly
 });
});
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, I already tried that, works, but I can't access the returned value outside of it block.

Comment: Declare the result variable on top directly inside describe block, outside any 'it' block.It will act as a global variable for 'it' blocks inside that describe block.

Comment: Then also no need to return the result variable.Just assign the value to it.

Comment: Prints out undefined ofc if we put it outside 'it' block, that is not the way on how this problem should be resolved.

Comment: I updated my answer with code to give you an more clear idea.